# Оптимальный способ полного обновления каталога в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

**Задача**: регулярно по расписанию обновлять всю структуру каталога (категории, товары, доп. таблицы, сводные таблицы связей многие ко многим) на основе **xml** файла выгрузки.

Необходимо парсить файл и на основе полученных данных наполнять\обновлять каталог.

Номенклатура довольно объёмная, около 30 тысяч товаров, десятки категорий и сотни тысяч записей в сводных таблицах.

**Проблема**: как выполнять эту процедуру оптимально, за минимальное время и с минимальный количеством запросов в БД.

**Мои предположения как это можно сделать**:

1. На каждой итерации выполнять `Product::updateOrCreate()` и аналогично для других моделей, а сводные таблицы обновлять с помощью `sync`.
2. Из выгрузки получить массивы товаров, категорий и т.п., затем несколькими запросами извлечь из БД соответственно все товары, категории и т.п. и в цикле сравнивать соответствующие записи и в случае отличия обновлять или добавлять записи в БД.

1 вариант кажется даст слишком большую нагрузку, т.к. на каждой итерации будут выполняться селекты для сравнения.

А вот по второму варианту у меня вопрос: как в Laravel лучше всего сравнивать объект из коллекции моделей с обычным массивом полей?
Нужно тупо последовательно сравнивать каждое поле или есть удобная функция для сравнения? В документации ничего такого не видел, но может опытные пользователи Laravel могут подсказать...

Comment: а дропнуть старое и влить новое нельзя?

Comment: Раньше я именно так и делал в нескольких проектах, но ведь тогда периодически будут пропадать некоторые позиции, а они могут быть связаны с другими сущностям, например заказами

Comment: Например из xml номенклатуры удалят какие-то товары, потому что они сняты с продажи, я бы хотел отслеживать эти моменты, поэтому пытаюсь придумать способ импортировать на сайт только изменения...

Comment: второй пункт можно упростить, если выбирать сразу на всё, а только id и hash. Создаёте hash сущности с номенклатуры, и тянете hash этой же сущности с базы. Если хеши не совпадут(или сущности в базе нет) - сохраняйте. Это должно секономить уйму ресурсов и времени

Comment: @AlexKhonko, т.е. выбрать все записи из базы, но только с 2мя полями id и hash? И сравнивать hash из базы со сгенерированным на лету хешем из новых данных?

Comment: да. +- так. Выбираете чанками данные со своего ресурса, и чанками просите в базе не прямо все сразу id|hash, а только те, которые сейчас нужны

Comment: @AlexKhonko, по моему отличное решение! Если не сложно, напишите чуть более развернутый ответ, я за него проголосую и вопрос будет исчерпан )

Comment: ок, после работы. Это будет ближе к 8-9 вечера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моей практике, когда нужно обработать большие объемы данных, из которых нужно сохранить/изменить только часть, использую следующий подход:

1. беру свои данные пачками, например, если источник например 1кк записей, то через банальный limit/offset,или between, или тип того
2. сущности, которые надо писать в базу, имеют некий метод `getHash`, который берёт и с сущности делают уникальный хеш исходя из данных, которые сохранятся
3. из базы вмето полноценных сущностей выбираю только id+hash, которые находятся в текущей пачке, и сравниваю по хешам, соответственно таким образом мы много экономим и памяти, и по скорости быстрее, потому что не надо создавать лишние связи, вызывать лишние конструкторы, и т.д

Comment: Можно ещё один уточняющий вопрос, мне ведь нужно в цикле пробегать по массиву новых данных которые я получил из парсера, как мне этот массив делить с помощью limit и offset? Я ведь должен сравнивать хеш из новых данных с хешем из базы и если в базе вообще нет такой сущности то добавлять, а если есть но хеши не сходятся то обновлять...

Comment: Или может мне из парсера собирать не массив , а коллекцию? Её можно как-то делить на порции?

Comment: уточните свои инструменты для парсинга(либы, функции, ...)

Comment: Да по сути не важно, главное я уже получил массивы новых данных, осталось реализовать обновление БД ) пакет называет DomCrawler от Symfony